# Cleanup ref issues in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I have a problem cause ESLINT outputs an error in console. I want to fix the issues in console.
Pls check codesandbox here

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/play-when-on-sight-le69k?file=/src/Player.js)

Update Issue

```
The 'callbackFunction' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 33) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'callbackFunction' in its own useCallback() Hook. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

Old Issues

```
The ref value 'containerRef.current' will likely have changed by the time this effect cleanup function runs. If this ref points to a node rendered by React, copy 'containerRef.current' to a variable inside the effect, and use that variable in the cleanup function. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
eslint

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'callbackFunction'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

**Code**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFunction, options);
    if (containerRef.current) observer.observe(containerRef.current);

    return () => {
      if (containerRef.current) observer.unobserve(containerRef.current);
    };
  }, [containerRef, options]);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The ref value `containerRef.current` will likely have changed by the
> time this effect cleanup function runs. If this ref points to a node
> rendered by React, copy `containerRef.current` to a variable inside
> the effect, and use that variable in the cleanup function.
> (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

Just save the current ref value to a locally scoped variable to be closed over in the  effect's cleanup function.

> React Hook `useEffect` has a missing dependency: `callbackFunction`.
> Either include it or remove the dependency array.
> (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

You will want to cleanup any old subscribed observers, refs, callbacks, etc... when, if ever, the `callbackFunction` value updates. Add it to the dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let observerRefValue = null; // <-- variable to hold ref value

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFunction, options);

  if (containerRef.current) {
    observer.observe(containerRef.current);
    observerRefValue = containerRef.current; // <-- save ref value
  }

  return () => {
    if (observerRefValue) observer.unobserve(observerRefValue); // <-- use saved value
  };
}, [callbackFunction, options]);
```

## Update

> The 'callbackFunction' function makes the dependencies of useEffect
> Hook (at line 33) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect
> callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'callbackFunction' in
> its own useCallback() Hook. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

You can either memoize this callback by wrapping in a `useCallback` hook:

```
const callbackFunction = React.useCallback((entries) => {
  const [entry] = entries;
  onIntersection(video.id, entry);
}, [onIntersection, video]);
```

Or you can simply move the callback ***into*** the `useEffect` hook and update the dependencies:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const callbackFunction = (entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    onIntersection(video.id, entry);
  };

  let observerRefValue = null;

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFunction, options);

  if (containerRef.current) {
    observer.observe(containerRef.current);
    observerRefValue = containerRef.current;
  }

  return () => {
    if (observerRefValue) observer.unobserve(observerRefValue);
  };
}, [onIntersection, options, video]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Now i have another error in codesandbox in callbackFunction. Can you check it? Thanks

Comment: @Joseph Sure, updated answer with suggestions.

Comment: @Joseph Sounds like you are possibly using `next.js` (?). Symptom sounds like stale state. If the next page is on the same route/path then my guess would be that it isn't reacting to updates to any route parameters that indicate the page has changed. Solution is to use `componentDidUpdate` (class-based component) or another `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency, to update whatever local state you might be using to render content.

Comment: @Joseph You can fork your sandbox and try converting to the Next.js template, and then add whatever code necessary to produce a running sandbox artifact that reproduces the issue. Full disclosure: I can help debug a running Next.js app, but I have 0 experience standing one up. I suggest working on getting a new sandbox created and asking a ***new*** question here on SO with appropriate tag(s), you'll likely get better help more quickly. Feel free to (at) me here with a link to question and I can take a look.

Comment: Refs aren't supposed to be used as dependencies in useEffect.

Comment: @JCraine You are correct that they are unnecessary, React is apparently smart enough to know they are a stable reference.

Answer (score 2):

With reference to your **update issue** you need to use useCallback

```
  const callbackFunction = useCallback((entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    onIntersection(video.id, entry);
  }, [video, onIntersection]);
```