# React ref.current is null in useEffect cleanup function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

I'm trying to access a ref during clean up (before the component unmounts).

Like so:

```js
const Comp = () => {
    const imgRef = React.useRef();

    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log('component mounted', imgRef); // During mount, imgRef.current is always defined
      return () => {
        console.log('component unmounting', imgRef); // imgRef.current always null here
      }
    }, []);  // also tried adding imgRef and imgRef.current still doesn't work in clean up

    return (
      <img src={'example.png'} ref={imgRef} />
    );

};
const App = () => {
  const [img, setImg] = React.useState(true);
  return <div>
    <button onClick={() => setImg(!img)}>toggle</button>
    {img && <Comp />}
  </div>;
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Even adding `imgRef` in the `useEffect`'s dependency, the imgRef.current is still null in the return of useEffect...

This works in the equivalent Class component with `componentWillUnmount` the imgRef is properly defined.

How can I make it work with hooks?

Comment: I made you a live snippet and, as you see, can't reproduce the problem - can you edit the snippet so that it demonstrates the problem you describe? (A `const` with an object initially assigned to it should never be `undefined`, so I'm doubtful...)

Comment: @CertainPerformance https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sun-uhv98f

Comment: Thanks @SteveK I was about to share this I just made: https://codesandbox.io/s/ref-undefined-clean-up-useeffect-me3j01?file=/src/App.js

But yours shows the same result - when the component unmounts ref.current is null

Comment: It's not `undefined` as your question says, it's null. Fix it with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67069936

Comment: @Jellohouse you can set the current ref as a constant before you return the cleanup function and then reference it in the return function. So set `const img = imageRef.current` before the return and then you can access it in the return function.

Comment: Thanks! Those solutions solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67069936

Something like this worked for me:

```js
const imgRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  let localRef = null;
  if (imgRef.current) localRef = imgRef.current;
  return () => {
     console.log('component unmounting', localRef); // localRef works here!
  }
}, []);

return (
  <img ref={imgRef} src="example.png" />
);
```