# No overload matches this call when passing custom function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am adding an event listener and upon event, I want to call a function that sets the state.

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useLayoutEffect} from 'react';

const [width, setWidthIn] = useState<number>(0)
const ref = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement>(null);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if(ref.current) ref.current.addEventListener('resize', setWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth))

    return ()=> {
        if(ref.current) ref.current.removeEventListener('resize', setWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth))
    }
},[])
```

However, this hightlights me `setWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth)` and says

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.

When I replace `setWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth)` with something like

```
 if(ref.current) ref.current.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

 const handleResize = () => {
     setWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth())
 }
```

it works. Why is that?

Comment: Does this depend on react? If so you might want to tag it as such. If not you might want to [edit] your example code so it only uses native TypeScript types and values

Comment: @jcalz Might be because of React, I added the tags

Comment: You're calling `setWidth` first, then passing the *returned value* of `setWidth` to the event listener, which is incorrect because it expects a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly :**
Resize event is not triggered on any element by default. It is only for window by the way. So i hope you are triggering it on your own. Otherwise listent to the window resize event as I have done in the below sandbox.

Regarding the question:

`ref.current.addEventListener('resize', setWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth))` this statement is problematic.

You are adding a listener in the second argument. That listener is supposed to be a function. `setWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth)` this is a function call, not a function. When this statement is encountered state is set and the return value of `setWidth` is added as the event listener.

The return value of `setWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth)` is void. That is what TS complains about. Here is a code-sandbox, where I have wrapped it in a function and assigned it. You can uncomment the first few statements and comment the other statements to find out. TS does not complain : https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-wilson-iy7mn3?file=/src/App.tsx

Also, remove event listener needs to be passed the function reference so it can be removed correctly. So ideally you should save the function in variable and then pass it to `removeEventListener`. Once again TS is complaining here about the return type of `setWidth`. Check the above sandbox where I have passed the function itself.

PS: The original question does not asks this but there is also a warning regarding the ref values. Look at this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67069827/cleanup-ref-issues-in-react) to solve that.

**Note:**

Comment: Is your fiddle working? It is not updating the width when I resize the window.

Comment: The fiddle works if you listen on window. It will not work with HeadingElement. Check note which i have already added.